# ReferenceError: window is not defined - is there a way to get the width of the device before loaded?

Tags: typescript, next.js, client-side

In NextJs page.jsx there will be the error in **useState**:
ReferenceError: window is not defined.
I think the reason is that since the component isn't mount yet window can not be found.
However, I want to get the width of my device to determine which device I'm using so that I can get the right amount of data. Is there another way of doing it??

```
export default function Home() {
  const applicationLimitWidth = 768;
  const queryClient = new QueryClient();
  const [windowWidth, setWindowWidth] = useState<number>(window.innerWidth);
  const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState<boolean>(
    windowWidth >= applicationLimitWidth ? false : true
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
      setWindowWidth(window.innerWidth);
    });
  }, []);
```

I tried to get the width after it is loaded, but in that case, it didn't render again.

Comment: Next.js uses SSR, so your component is actually rendered on the *server*, and then that is sent to the client, which is then hydrated once the JavaScript is executed. You need to add `if (typeof window !== "undefined")` before you use browser-specific globals.